# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a UnitTest and should test this method. I am getting the sum of strings. What I did is that I converted the string into integers and added them and store in the variable length as an Integer, and then I return the length. The problem that I have is that it is showing that it cannot resolve symbol length. I am using Rider as IDE and I changed the settings of the IDE, but it is still showing "Cannot resolve symbol length". I hope someone can help me to fix this.

```
internal string SumStrings(string value1, string value2)
{            
    int.Parse(length) = int.Parse(value1) + int.Parse(value2);
    return length;            
}
```

The UnitTest:

#region Sum of strings as string

```
// Create a method that returns the sum of two numbers.
    [Fact]
    public void ReturnsSumAsStringFromTwoString()
    {
        Assert.Equal("11", util.SumStrings("6","5"));
    }

    // Previous method must pass the following Multiple tests.
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("1", "1", "0")]
    [InlineData("1", "0", "1")]
    [InlineData("-1", "0", "-1")]
    [InlineData("1000", "500", "500")]
    public void TheoriesReturnsSumAsStringFromTwoString(string length, string value1, string value2)
    {
        Assert.Equal(length, util.SumStrings(value1, value2));
    }
```

Comment: IMHO look into [Int.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you declare and assign a variable:

```
int.Parse(length) = int.Parse(value1) + int.Parse(value2);
```

This is:

```
var length = int.Parse(value1) + int.Parse(value2);
```

Or if you want to specify the type explicitly:

```
int length = int.Parse(value1) + int.Parse(value2);
```

Additionally, your method claims to have a return type of `string` but you are trying to return an `int`.  Change the return type:

```
internal int SumStrings(string value1, string value2) {
```

As an aside, in your method you don't really need a separate variable at all, you can just return the calculated result directly:

```
internal int SumStrings(string value1, string value2) {
    return int.Parse(value1) + int.Parse(value2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to do `int.Parse(length)` while the length is not defined yet,
and you are not returning a string but an Int.

```
internal string SumStrings(string value1, string value2)
{            
    var length = int.Parse(value1) + int.Parse(value2);
    return length.ToString();            
}
```

would work, but be careful, what would happen if the input is not a number?
better use TryParse

```
int number;

bool success = int.TryParse(value, out number);
```

a better solution would be something like this:

```
    internal string SumStrings(string value1, string value2)
    {
         if (int.TryParse(value1, out var num1) && int.TryParse(value2, out var num2))
         {
             return (num1+num2).ToString();
         }


         
         // throw new WrongInputException("wrong input");   
         // or some other default behavior as your requirements ask for
         // basically some kind of handling for bad input value
  }
```

as the comments section implies, you should of course catch the specific exception, and even create a new exception that suits your needs

Comment: IMO throwing an `Exception` (especially just a generic `Exception` if `TryParse` fails) isn't really a better solution.  The whole "Try" aspect allows you to avoid exceptions entirely, so there are far better ways to handle it, like re-prompting for input.

Comment: @CodeStranger, of course! i agree, but i dont know what are the requirements of the task, i wouldn't just return -1 or int.MinValue,  so this should be implemented as the requirements ask for, anyway, it is better then failing with a format exception

Comment: *"what would happend if the input is not a number?"* - It would throw a more specific exception than the one your solution throws...

Comment: @David, there should be some kind of handling of that exception,
they should create a custom exception for this case and handle it accordingly,
again as i said, this should be according to the question requirements..

Comment: @David, and the point of my answer is to enlighten the possibility that maybe the developer missed a use case of his requirements. I believe my point was delivered

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more clear about that section

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal Thank you. It works now. This helped me: internal string SumStrings(string value1, string value2)
{            
    var length = int.Parse(value1) + int.Parse(value2);
    return length.ToString();            
}

Comment: @ChristianH if my answer helped you, you can mark it with the check and accept it

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal Not enough reputation to check mark it.